# Upload File From Windows to Unix via SFTP Jsch error with null values directory path

Tags: java, file-upload, sftp, jsch

I'm using JSch to upload file via sftp.

im uploading file from windows to unix server

Upon uploading im using

```
ChannelSFTP.put(file)
```

As such:

```
File file = FiletoPath;
sftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
```

This However will appear as since getName() will return name of file or absolute path:

> \\something\something\something\Documents$\something\something\myfilename.txt

when I try to split it will have error

```
String[] split = file.getName().split("\\");
sftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), split[split.length-1]);
```

I am out of idea. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: when it upload to server it save as \something\something\something\Documents$\something\something\myfilename.txt instead of myfilename.txt

Comment: What about using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). ?

Answer (score 0):

I have Soved it.

Basically due to

> \\ this back slashes they will have a null value and will throw an exception

I use org.google.guava.Splitter.jar:
Download it online [org.google.guava.Splitter.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/18.0)

Below my snippet code:

```
//Declaration of JSch Connection session,
//channel and ChannelSftp
//filetype: MultiPartFile

String filename = file.getName();
Iterables<String> itr = Splitter.on("\\").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(filename);
String[] split = Iterables.toArray(itr);

ChannelSftp.put:

//Change Directory to upload the file:
String uploadDirectoryPath = "/usr/name/profile/toStorePath/files/";

try{
     csftp.cd(uploadDirectoryPath);
     csftp.put(file.getInputStream(), split[split.length-1]);
} catch(SftpException | IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```